# Unable to disable smart quotes in Pycharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to change

```
            order_by_col = entity.orderByColumns
```

to

```
            order_by_col = entity["orderByColumns"]
```

(note there are dozens of these)

But instead the dreaded "smart typing" comes into play and `pycharm` does this to me after typing the first `"`:

```
order_by_col = entity["."]orderByColumns
```

I had turned off smart-quotes ages ago:

[image]

Why doesn't that do the trick?  How do I tell `Pycharm` to stop interfering here?

*Update* I added `intellij-idea` tag since presumably the behavior would be similar?

Comment: (FWIW, the easiest way to do this transformation is with a quick regex replace, or if you want to do it by hand, double click/select the name, then type the quote)

Comment: it comes up constantly when editing: i have to highlight and delete two characters after inserting the quote.  I'm not talking about retroactively fixing an entire file.